# MS access 2010 form filter doesn't match date field in some records. Returns incomplete record subset

Tags: ms-access, filter, ms-access-2010

I'd be extremely grateful for any suggestions on how to fix this for I've run out of ideas.

When trying to open a form to a subset of records, using the filter function of the form on a date field in the table, I noticed that some records are consistently missing. For example, I have 8 records with a certain date in my table, but if I filter for that date, only 6 of them are returned.

The table field is formatted as Date/Time, Short date. I checked for leading or trailing spaces and inconsistent use of zeros, but found nothing.  The records were imported from Excel files, where the field in question was also formatted as Date/Time. The date field is part of the composite primary key for the table together with one other field. I removed and re-did the primary key in case this was an faulty index issue but it didn't help. I deleted the date for one of the records and re-entered it manually but it didn't fix the issue for that record. I did the "Compact and Repair" with no success. I've looked at a sample of about 40 records and I can't find anything that distinguishes the ones that are returned by the filter from the ones that get lost, not even which Excel file they were originally imported from.

If I use a select query instead of the form filter, I get the complete subset. I could use a query in the background to do what I need to do, but I'd prefer to fix the underlying problem if possible.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: What data type is the field in question? Could you provide a sample of your data including the offending date?

Answer (score 0):

The fields maybe are formatted but the issue maybe what is really written.
Go to table where the data are stored and check the entries
One simple solution is to use the DateValue function

```
Me.Filter = "DateValue(TheFieldYouWantToPerformFiltering) = #" & theDateYouUseToFilter & "#"
```